# Record audio+video in python webkit gtk+ browser

Tags: html, webrtc, pygtk

I have been trying to record video and audio using simple web browser that i build using webkit gtk+ with python.

I tried this demo and made one that work in chrome and firefox
https://addpipe.com/media-recorder-api-demo/
and when i tried in my simple web browser it said that MediaRecorder not supported.

Is webkit gtk+ does not support it? or anyone have a way to do it?